# Need to clone a hard drive containing Windows 7 and Ubuntu OSes?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have a 120GB hard drive which contains 3 partitions- Windows 7, the 100MB partition for booting and then an Ubuntu partition.

I have just bought a 240GB SSD which i'd like to use to expand the Windows 7 and Ubuntu partitions on, without losing any data.

What would be the best application to do this? And should I copy the partitions across before I increase the size?

Answer (score 0):

Try clonezilla and no do not resize till afterwards.  Use partedmagic to resize the hard drive.